Parallel Running Question for numeric solver and optimization
I've been trying to calibrate some parameters using optimization which runs a numeric solver (solver.out) for numerous time.
Main executor (run.py) calls the optimization class (DEA.py).
DEA creates a candidate solutions (N, 50 up to 500) pool and each solution writes 6-10 .txt files as input. Subprocess.call runs the numeric solver (solver.out) and writes an output text file.
DEA evaluate the performance of the candidate solution and create new mutant solution until stopping criteria is satisfied.

Traditional sequantial evolution of the candidate solution in DEA is infeasible. I need to parallelized that process using multithreading or multiprocessing. I have couple of question.

Pool.starmap seems a good solution for the problem but cpu utilization is limited. Can I use multithreading and run maybe 250 execution (solver.out) same time.
parallelized solutions have access to same input and output files. Is that problem for writing reading .txt files and running the solver.out file.

I tried to create workers using python pool.starmap but my cpu limit is up to 8. I need to seriliazed the running process of solver for each solution in the pool.

Multithreading is limited by the GIL in Python. It only worth it if you use functions that release the GIL but most do not release it (except some functions of computing modules like Numpy). Even if you use functions releasing the GIL, the GIL is often locked/unlocked frequently in interpreted codes so the function locking/unlocking it needs to unlock it for a sufficiently long time for the code to scale. The Amdahl's law states only a fraction of the time spent in a sequential code (e.g. locked by the GIL) causes the scalability to decrease a lot. TL;DR: CPython's multithreading sucks.

Multiprocessing can introduce a significant overhead because of interprocess communication and pickling in CPython (mandatory to move objects between the interpreter processes). I may fit your needs if the solver is a very intensive parts and the amount of data copied is not huge so the overhead can be negligible.

Reading in the same file in parallel is fine, but writing in the same file in parallel is not safe. It often causes a race condition unless you can ensure the modified parts of the file are independent and modified parts do not impact others (no appending not removal of section -- only modifications). The best solution is generally to write in independent files and then merge them, or to use an API specifically designed to avoid such issues (MPI provide that for example, and MPI can also be used to parallelize some HPC application more easily/efficiently than multiprocessing IMHO).

I matched each solution with different workers which sends the parallel processing to separate files for writing text files. I should use cpu clusters to save time. Each run takes 60-120 seconds and one generation improvement requires more than 3 hours for 100 population pool size. Thank you for your answer.
